# about java mail search

Tags: java, email

I can't find mail using java mail fodler.search

I use java mail fodler.search Whatever the search() argument is, the resulting message is an empty array

```
        ReceiveMailSession receiveMailSession = createReceiveMailSession();
        receiveMailSession.open();

        List<EmailListDTO> emailListDTOList = new ArrayList<>();

        SearchTerm searchTerm = buildSearchTerm(searchDTO);
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(searchDTO.getFolder())) {
            Folder folder = receiveMailSession.getFolder(searchDTO.getFolder());
            if (folder.exists()) {
                folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
                Message[] messages = folder.search(searchTerm);
                for (Message message : messages) {
                    emailListDTOList.add(messageToEmailListDTO(message, null));
                }
                folder.close(true);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Folder is an abstract class, and getFolder is an abstract method! You should use an extended instance of Folder of either the IMAP or POP3 type, and assign an instance with getFolder method not continually declare the same code. What API are you using? This?    https://javadoc.io/static/org.jodd/jodd-mail/3.8.5/jodd/mail/ReceiveMailSession.html

Comment: @Samuel Marchant
Thank you for your answer. Yes, I used this API. I was able to get messages in this folder through the getMessages method, but using the search method will return an empty array

Comment: @Samuel Marchant this version : https://javadoc.io/static/org.jodd/jodd-mail/6.0.5/jodd/mail/ReceiveMailSession.html#%3Cinit%3E(javax.mail.Session,javax.mail.Store,java.io.File)

Comment: The code you were using was mixing Ali's , while you can you would need to obtain the part of the kids API and then from that the part of that, that is standard API mail to use the standard piece of API.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem that I couldn't use a subclass of SearchTerm

```
//error
 SearchTerm term1 = new SubjectTerm("123");
//success
SearchTerm term = new SearchTerm() {
    public boolean match(Message message) {
        try {
            if (message.getSubject().contains("test")) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: javax.mail.search.SearchTerm is also abstract, so take a look at the API docs for its direct known subclasses.   javax.mail.search.StringTerm , the folder and messages in the first post you can search that way. You may need to set StringTerm ignorecase.